# How can I get ........ of extra characteres of edittext in android?

Tags: android

I am new to android and my task is to display `......` when entered more characters in `EditText`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Plz explain better what you need.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to understand. Is that what you're looking for - the following appends dots when the text does not fit:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1" 
android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
android:lines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="password"
    />
```